# Changing comments avatar

Tags: plugins, avatar, quick-edit

Is there a plugin that lets me change an avatar of a comment?
Since I can edit comments, is it possible to add avatars as well?

I don't have registered user on my blog, only guests and those who connect to comments via Facebook. Those that use FB authorization have an avatar but those who comment without one don't. I would like to be able to manually change an avatar of individual comments.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to selectively change avatars because they are generated from emails, for which you are not aware if they have a avatar associated

Answer (score 2):

You could use the auto generated Gravatar options in the back end which will randomly assign an "avatar" to those who do not have one. You will find this when you go to your WordPress back-end **Settings > Discussion** and scroll down to the bottom.

Or you can have a custom avatar replacement for those who do not have one however this will not be random but will ad a custom a default avatar to your site. You can do this by simply putting this in your comments.php file via your theme where you would be putting your avatars:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 96, get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/avatar.jpg' ); ?>
```

Just make sure you have an image in your images folder called avatar.jpg . By the way 96 is the size of the avatar in pixels. You can adjust the size by making the number larger (for a larger avatar) or smaller.

I hope this helps. :)

---

**EDIT:**

I am not sure if this is something you might be interested because it allows people to upload their own avatars and is a Gravatar alternative. However this plugin does say that it allows avatar control. I have not tried it but you might want to give this a go:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-local-avatar/

Comment: Thanks, I know that I can use custom avatar by default but I was wondering if I there was a plugin that enables me to change an avatar on comment basis so that I can change each and every avatar in comments.

Comment: @rlesko I made an edit to my answer above. You might want to check out the plugin I have found.

Comment: Generally, to change per-user data, you need to modify user meta data - and in order to have user meta data to modify, you need to have *registered Users*. With anonymous users, you're pretty much stuck with using a default avatar, or else using an email address-based avatar (Gravatar, or one of the generated avatars).

Comment: @rlesko I agree here with Chip. He is correct.

Comment: I believe there is a way to change the avatar for each comment as it is possible to edit comment content. When you edit a comment, you can change author's name, email, URL and an actual comment so I don't see why an avatar couldn't be changed.